# Javascript concurrent requests script uses maximum of 80 Mbps on a 1 Gbps network

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, concurrency, axios

I am having an issue where I am running 200 concurrent GET requests in JS using 60 http proxies. Each request is downloading a 1.6 MB (megabyte) file. The proxies have speeds of 300-400 ms. The network download speed is typically 1000 Mbps to 1500 Mbps (megabits per second). I am running this script on a Windows Server.
See the screenshot here: [Ookla Speed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXOXF.png)

```html
async function sendRequest(kw, anchor, proxy, cb) {

    const [ip, port, user, pass] = proxy.split(':')
  
    var url = /*some api endpoint*/
    var options = {
        headers: {
            'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
            'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8",
            'cache-control': "max-age=0",
            'if-none-match': "W/\"701c0-GT5kESYD+JEYlkRTfHGT3PH+PTI\"",
            'sec-ch-ua': "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"89\", \"Chromium\";v=\"89\", \";Not A Brand\";v=\"99\"",
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': "?0",
            'sec-fetch-dest': "document",
            'sec-fetch-mode': "navigate",
            'sec-fetch-site': "none",
            'sec-fetch-user': "?1",
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': "1"
        },
        proxy: {
          host: ip,
          port: port,
          auth: {
              username: user,
              password: pass
          }
      }
  
    }
  
    axios.get(url, options).then(res => cb(res))
  
  }
  
let proxies = [/*proxies go here*/]
  let kws = [/*keywords go here*/]
  
  let responses = []
  
  let starttime
  let finishtime
  
  function sendRequests(limit) {
    if (limit > kws.length) return console.log('limit exceeds request kws')
    for(let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      console.log('sending request......')
      sendRequest(kws[i], '50', proxies[i], function (res) {
        console.log('status: '+res.status)
        responses.push(res)
        if(responses.length == limit) {
          finishtime = returnTimeMilliseconds()
          console.log('Finished '+limit+' requests in ' + (finishtime - starttime)/1000 + ' seconds')
        }
      })  
    }
  }

  function returnTimeMilliseconds() {
    var d = new Date();
  
    return d.getTime()
  }

  starttime = returnTimeMilliseconds()
  sendRequests(200)
```

A single request takes an average of 1.5-2 seconds. Up to 5 concurrent requests, the requests return in 1.5-2 seconds from sending them all to the last request coming in. This makes sense given the definition of concurrency. However when running a larger number like 10, 20, or 200, it almost always takes way too long for the first request to resolve - about 5 to 10 seconds - and for all of the requests to resolve the ratio is about 5 requests per second.

At any time my network usage while running this program hits 80 Mbps Maximum, found by using Resource Monitor on windows.

I have ran this script on 2 different wifi networks, the first was a 30 Mbps network. I experienced longer wait times there but the entire 30 Mbps was being used, so speeds were typically 3.45 MBps (megabytes per second). Here, the speed should be 125 to 187.5 MBps but the result is drastically less.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Version of node? Does axios change maxSockets (I do not use it)

Comment: axios-https-proxy-fix, 0.17.1